# How to get the day name from the date string regardless of user's timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

Given a date (without time) e.g. `2021-08-11`, how could I get its day name (e.g. Wednesday) regardless of the user's timezone?

Note that trying to use:

```
new Date("2021-08-11").toLocaleString('en-AU', { weekday:'long' })
```

or `date-fns`'s `format`:

```
format(new Date("2021-08-11"), "EEEE")
```

results in the wrong day (Tuesday) if the user's timezone is GMT-7, for example.

Comment: You're looking for server-time then, because user time-zones will always vary. You'd reference either/or depending on use-case.

Comment: `new Date("2021-08-11").getDay()` - Is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz) as suggested by the other comment. It interally uses `Intl`. If you only care about getting the day you can just use `Intl` directly:

```js
let formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
  timeZone: 'UTC',
  weekday: 'long',
});

formatter.format(new Date("2021-08-11")) // outputs: "Wednesday"
```

I would recommend that you also format your dates to ISO i.e. `"2021-08-11T00:00:00.000Z"` as the `Z` at the end will ensure that the date is parsed in UTC before formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't surveyed the latest `data-fns`.  But when I used it a couple of years ago, it didn't have a timezone support.  Since the `Date` class does not keep the timezone information internally, it causes some problems when the location of time acquisition is different from where it is used.  See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone/15171030#15171030) for details.

There are some libraries available to solve this problem.  Since you are using `date-fns` you might want to try [date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz).